# Batch coding nested loop issue

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to iterate values using a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) but I am not getting expected results. Based on the actual output I think the nested loop is not required here, but I am not sure how can I achieve Expected output without loops.

```
@Echo Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set "Ids=1,2"
Set "basePath=C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\"
Set "fileName=test1,test2"
Set "extension=.csv"
echo ****Configuation Details****
Echo basePath - %basePath%
Echo fileName - %fileName%
Echo extension - %extension%
echo.
For %%i in (%Ids%) do (
    For %%f in (%fileName%) do (
        echo Id - %%i and file name - %%f
        Set "completepath=%basePath%%%f%extension%"
        echo completepath - !completepath!
        FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (!completepath!) do (
            echo Result of api command1 call for Id : %%i and fileName: %%f
            echo.
        )
    )
)
Pause
```

Current Output:

```
****Configuation Details****
basePath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\
fileName - test1,test2
extension - .csv

Id - 1 and file name - test1
completepath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\test1.csv
Result of api command1 call for Id : 1 and fileName: test1

Id - 1 and file name - test2
completepath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\test2.csv
Result of api command1 call for Id : 1 and fileName: test2

Id - 2 and file name - test1
completepath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\test1.csv
Result of api command1 call for Id : 2 and fileName: test1

Id - 2 and file name - test2
completepath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\test2.csv
Result of api command1 call for Id : 2 and fileName: test2
```

Expected Output:

```
****Configuation Details****
basePath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\
fileName - test1,test2
extension - .csv

Id - 1 and file name - test1
completepath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\test1.csv
Result of api command1 call for Id : 1 and fileName: test1

Id - 2 and file name - test2
completepath - C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\test2.csv
Result of api command1 call for Id : 2 and fileName: test2
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to map an ID to a file name. If that's the case, you should use arrays instead.

Comment: Well, you seem to misunderstand the concept of nested (`for`) loops. Given that `Id` is always numeric and consecutive, remove the `for %%i` loop, do `set /A "Id=0"` before the `for %%f` loop, do `set /A "Id+=1"` as first command in the loop body and use `!Id!` instead of `%%i`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are using numeric and consecutive `Id`s, [aschipfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57555026/4561332) is best suited for your needs.

Here is a more general approach to give you an idea what can be done is the case that the `Id`s are not numeric or are random.

```
set NameIdPairs="test1,1", "test2,2", "Filename with spaces,0xfca"
set "basePath=C:\Users\Documents\ReusableQueries\"
set "extension=.csv"

for %%P in (%NameIdPairs%) do (
    echo Current Pair: %%P
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%F in (%%P) do (
        echo Id - %%G and file name - %%F
        set "completepath=%basePath%%%F%extension%"
        echo completepath - !completepath!
    )
)
```

Each pair of `filename` and `id` are grouped in the format `"filename,id"`
There must not be any spaces around the comma(`,`) which separates them or else they will become part the `filename` and or `id`

The pair themselves are separated from each other by comma(`,`) and/or spaces.

The outer loop picks one pair at each iteration then the inner loop tokenizes the pair to extract the `filename` and `id`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand the concept of nested (`for`) loops: they do not loop parallelly, rather the inner loop runs in every iteration of the outer one.

So to get what you want, given that `Id` is always numeric and consecutive, remove the `for %%i` loop, do `set /A "Id=0"` before the `for %%f` loop, do `set /A "Id+=1"` as first command in the loop body and use `!Id!` instead of `%%i`, like this:

```cmd
rem // Your code before the loop structure, except `set "Ids=1,2"`...
echo/
set /A "Id=0"
for %%f in (%fileName%) do (
    set /A "Id+=1"
    echo Id - !Id! and file name - %%f
    set "completepath=%basePath%%%f%extension%"
    echo completepath - !completepath!
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("!completepath!") do (
        echo Result of api command1 call for Id : !Id! and fileName: %%f
        echo/
    )
)
rem // Your code after the loop structure...
```

Comment: what if Id value is not 1,2 instead its some random number. example, Id=4,8 and I want to display
 Id= 4 and filename = test1
Id= 8 and filename = test2

Comment: Well, what about `set /A "Id+=4"` then?

Comment: Thanks but this approach have an additional step of maintaining Id's value at 2 places in the code.
At start Set "Ids=4,8" and then set /A "Id+=4" 

Moreover, like I said Id=4,8 is just an example, Id value could any numeric value in any pattern.